# Espalhe colunas com número diferente de duplicatas em R

Tags: r

Eu tenho um data.frame com número diferente de linhas de ID duplicadas e quero manter as colunas lado a lado das duplicadas.

Exemplo simples do que preciso fazer:

Como ir daqui:

[image: My df]

para aqui:

[image: The df i want]

---

### Dados

```
dados <- data.frame(
  ID = c("A", "A", "B", "C", "A", "C", "D", "D", "Z"),
  V2 = 1:9
)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para usar a função `pivot_wider` do pacote `tidyr`, tem primeiro de crair uma coluna com valores únicos em cada linha dos grupos de `ID`. Cria-se então uma coluna auxiliar, `V`.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dplyr))
library(tidyr)

dados <- data.frame(
  ID = c("A", "A", "B", "C", "A", "C", "D", "D", "Z"),
  V2 = 1:9
)

dados %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(V = row_number() + 1L,
         V = paste0("V", V)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = ID,
    names_from = V,
    values_from = V2,
    values_fill = NA
  )
#> # A tibble: 5 x 4
#>   ID       V2    V3    V4
#>   <chr> <int> <int> <int>
#> 1 A         1     2     5
#> 2 B         3    NA    NA
#> 3 C         4     6    NA
#> 4 D         7     8    NA
#> 5 Z         9    NA    NA
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Uma alternativa a `paste0` é [`sprintf`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sprintf.html).

```r
dados %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(V = sprintf("V%d", row_number() + 1L)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = ID,
    names_from = V,
    values_from = V2,
    values_fill = NA
  )
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

## Edição

Se a base tiver mais colunas de valores, por exemplo `V2`, `V3` e `V4`, muda-se

- a variável auxiliar é simplificada para o resultado ter nomes mais claros;
- o argumento `values_from` deve ter um valor que identifique as colunas a expandir.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dplyr))
library(tidyr)

dados2 <- data.frame(
  ID = c("A", "A", "B", "C", "A", "C", "D", "D", "Z"),
  V2 = 1:9,
  V3 = 10:18,
  V4 = 19:27
)

dados2 %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(V = row_number() + 1L) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = ID,
    names_from = V,
    values_from = matches("V\\d+"),
    values_fill = NA
  )
#> # A tibble: 5 x 10
#>   ID     V2_2  V2_3  V2_4  V3_2  V3_3  V3_4  V4_2  V4_3  V4_4
#>   <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#> 1 A         1     2     5    10    11    14    19    20    23
#> 2 B         3    NA    NA    12    NA    NA    21    NA    NA
#> 3 C         4     6    NA    13    15    NA    22    24    NA
#> 4 D         7     8    NA    16    17    NA    25    26    NA
#> 5 Z         9    NA    NA    18    NA    NA    27    NA    NA
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Uma dúvida, na situação real tenho 40 variáveis que precisaria multiplicar pelo numero de cada ID duplicado e não só V2 como fiz no exemplo. Como faria isso?

Comment: @LuccaNielsen Feito com 3 variáveis, veja  a edição.

Comment: Ótimo. apenas mais uma pergunta, essa solução funcionaria se as colunas não estiverem nomeadas como V1, V2, V3 e sim com nomes aleatórios?

Comment: @LuccaNielsen Não, não resultaria. Tem que ter uma maneira de identificar as colunas, Se, por exemplo, forem todas excepto a primeira, pode fazer `values_from = -1` ou por nome, `values_from = -ID`. (Por nome é melhor, não depende da posição.)

Answer (score 5):

Mesma [solução de Rui Barradas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/544806/117168), mas com *data.table*:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(dados) # seta como data.table

dados[, col := paste0("V", 1:.N), ID] # cria identificador para as novas colunas

dcast(dados, ID ~ col, value.var = "V2")
#>    ID V1 V2 V3
#> 1:  A  1  2  5
#> 2:  B  3 NA NA
#> 3:  C  4  6 NA
#> 4:  D  7  8 NA
#> 5:  Z  9 NA NA
```